# White label Error Page load when page refresh (angular route with spring boot)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring-boot, ngroute, angularjs-ng-route

I am trying to add angular roue configuration to spring boots java application. urls are working well. bu problem is when i click back button or page refresh, there is an error. error said 'Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback'. how to config server angular route with spring boot.

my route configurations

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp',['ngTable','jcs-autoValidate','ngRoute']);

// configure our routes
app.config(function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider
    .when('/test', {
        templateUrl : 'template.jsp'


    })
        .when('/ct', {
            templateUrl : 'ct.jsp',
            controller  : 'myCtrl'

        })
        .when('/qa', {
            templateUrl : 'qa.jsp',
            controller  : 'ourCon'

        })


    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

my menu

```
 <a href="ct"> CT </a>
 <a href="qa"> QA </a>
```

how to solve this issue.

Comment: Sounds like you haven't configured server for html5Mode

Comment: Dear charlietfl.. how i do it.. can u help me

Comment: I don't know much about Spring but I'm sure it won't be hard to find out in a search

Comment: any one can help to solve this ??

Comment: @charlietfl I am also facing same issue? What is the solution u followed